# storageError[] while uploading file to awss3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, multer

I am working on NextJS application where I need to develop a functionality of file uploading in aws s3 bucket. I have created below api to upload a file however I am getting error in response

Error: Unexpected end of form
at Multipart._final (\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:569:17)
at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:694:27)
at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:723:7)
at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:733:5)
at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:631:5)
at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
storageErrors: []

Below is my api code

```
import { s3Uploadv3 } from '../../../lib/s3';
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 10000000000, files: 1 },
});

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method, query: { type } } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case 'POST':
      try {
        upload.single('file')(req, res, async (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send(err);
          }
          console.log('in upload');
          const results = await s3Uploadv3([req.file.buffer]); // Use buffer instead of file
          console.log(results);

          // Extract file URL
          const fileURL = results[0].fileURL; // Access the first (and only) result
          console.log(fileURL);
          return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', fileURL });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(404).send('Not found');
      }
  }
}
```

Frontend request call

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/fileUpload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
  
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file:', error.message);
    }
  };
```